# Why an extension is blocking a touch event in tableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, swift2

My UITableView used to work and sudendly it stopped to act as it was intended. I've found the segues are still doable but not just touching the cell, you need to hold the button and slide and then it does the segue. The delegates methods aren't called when a single touch is done. After being researching for a while, I think the best idea is to post my issue here, because looking in stackoverflow, seems that nobody have a similar issue.

I can click on the shop and the shop gets selected, but I have to maintain the button pressed, not a lot of time, a few miliseconds, almost instantly. The row turns gray but nothing happen. If I release the button then nothing happens too. if I slide then it does the segue. <s>There is nowhere in my code or even in my whole project were I have added a single gesture</s>. I've found an extension in my code that actually adds a gesture to my father `viewController` custom class. Find it in below

This is my table view code:

```
    //
//  showShopsTableView.swift
//  yuApp
//
//  Created by Alfredo on 16/5/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Alfredo. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class showShopsTableView : ViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var selectedRow : shopsTableViewCell!
    var index : Int = 0
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!


    @IBOutlet weak var currentTableView: UITableView!

    let resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)

    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var filtered:[String] = []


    override func viewDidLoad(){

        self.currentTableView?.delegate = self;
        self.currentTableView?.dataSource = self;

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Retrieve data asynchronously
        let call = webApi()
        call.retrieveOneCityShops{(success) in

            self.doTableRefresh()
        }

        viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        /*
        if let rect = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame {
            let y = rect.size.height + rect.origin.y
            self.currentTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake( y, 0, 0, 0)
        }*/
    }

    //Segue Method
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! detailViewShop

        sendVariablesToDetailView(destinationViewController)

    }
    //Set variables in the next view controller before do a segue
    func sendVariablesToDetailView(destinationViewController : detailViewShop){
        destinationViewController.dataSend = self.selectedRow
        destinationViewController.titleText = self.selectedRow.shopName.text
        destinationViewController.descriptionText = self.selectedRow.shopDescription.text
        destinationViewController.imageOutlet = self.selectedRow.shopImg
        destinationViewController.shopCategory = self.selectedRow.label1.text
        destinationViewController.brands = self.selectedRow.label2.text
    }

    //TableView Delegate Methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedRow = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! shopsTableViewCell
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("cell", sender: self)
    }


    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        /*
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        */
        return TableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : shopsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shopCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! shopsTableViewCell
        cell.shopName.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopDescription.text = values[indexPath.row].address
        cell.label1.text = values[indexPath.row].city
        cell.label2.text = values[indexPath.row].distance + "Km"
        cell.shopImg = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(named: "versace_shop.jpg"))
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 125
    }
    //SearchBar Delegate Methods
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filtered = TableData.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.currentTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        currentTableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func doTableRefresh(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.currentTableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }


}
```

EDIT: to remove all images that were showing the property `userInteractionEnabled` to TRUE. I've finally found the source of the issue. It has nothing to do with storyBoard. Is an extension I wrote for my main custom class, `viewController` (and so parent of this window too). The extension is that one:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
// Put this piece of code anywhere you like
extension ViewController {
    func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

It was called at the very beginning of my custom `viewController` class, right after `super.viewDidLoad()`:

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//      Hide keyboard when tap away

        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
```

I've commented `super.viewDidLoad()` in my `showShopsTableView` class and now is working just fine.
I'm not really sure to understand why this piece of code is blocking the touch event of my tableView, so if somebody wants to explain it, I will accept his answer. Also some points to my question would be very appreciated if you found it usefull.
In any case, thanks a lot to all that spend a minute here.

Comment: In storyboard, just disable the user interaction for textviews, textfields, labels.

Comment: Check for the user Interaction for the object that you have in the cell as said by Minkle Garg

Comment: Already checked that, and it's okay. Editing post with captures

Comment: I've added some captures of storyboard properties. Please check it out and do not hesitate to ask for more captures or details or code...